# Get SQL Server query metadata

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, metadata

The question I have is whether it is possible either in C# using native or other APIs or in SQL Server to access a SQL query's metadata.

Finding the schema information is easy enough when dealing with a standard `SELECT` statement, but it becomes more difficult when doing something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnA]) as 'CountResult' 
FROM MyTable
```

The goal being to find out the source column(s) for `CountResult` or even just the statement that created the alias.

Comment: Hmmm, somehow I think you are asking about more than INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns and Tables.  Where does the original query come from?  Can you give an example of what the source column might be?

Comment: The statement can be anything.  We just want to know how to pull out the Column Alias and then its source.  Kind of like parsing, but I assume this information can be had from existing resources.  So in the above instance I'd like to get access to 'ColumnResult' and the find out what created it.  In this instance it would be 'COUNT(DISTINCT [ColumnA])'.

Comment: I really want to know what the Schema for any given select statement will look like (the shape), plus for any given alias, where it came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help: `SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable();`

Comment: This is perfect for getting the resulting Column Names from a given query, but not for finding out where they derived from if they are Aliases.

Comment: Sorry, did not read carefully enough, I think without analyzing query source - you can not get what you need, because, after SQL creates result set it does not retain source information on what was the source of values. Just to illustrate the complexity: what would you return in your metadata for something like `Sum(a.Amount * b.Qty)` if you were SQL server?

Comment: Right, which makes me think I may be forced to go down the route of parsing the query for complicated cases such as that.  Was hoping to avoid that path if possible.  Thanks, sir!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Management Views (DMVs) also provide quite a bit of system information.  To get a quick list, you can run this query list in this [blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/15/sql-server-list-all-the-dmv-and-dmf-on-server/).  The DMV names are pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this helps, but you can get some info in execution plan. For example, execute you query with SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON statement before. It returns xml with detailed info about statement. The only problem is, that there is a lot of info, so your simple query sample will get this such code for list of output columns.

```
<OutputList>
    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1234" />
</OutputList>
```

By looking the Expr1234 you can find that result from Expr2345 is casted to int:

```
<ColumnReference Column="Expr1234" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr2345],0)">
    <Convert DataType="int" Style="0" Implicit="1">
        <ScalarOperator>
            <Identifier>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr2345" />
            </Identifier>
        </ScalarOperator>
    </Convert>
</ScalarOperator>
```

Next step will be to find Expr2345, where you can get that this is:

```
<ColumnReference Column="Expr2345" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="Count(*)">
    <Aggregate AggType="countstar" Distinct="0" />
</ScalarOperator>
```

So if you need exact column statement as it was in query, it will be hard to get it from plan. But if custom format allowed, just to get understanding what happens in column, this way might helps.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach.  Thanks a bunch.